# Stimulsoft "stireport" component is disabled on Visual Studio 2022 toolbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, stimulsoft

I've been trying to use stiReport component in my Winforms project but the component is disabled. I've imported it correctly, I don't know what would cause this, I'd be thankful for any sort of advice

PS: the stimulsoft version is 2022 and the Visual Studio version is also 2022.

[this is the problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ybjp3.png)

Comment: You might get a quicker answer by contacting the stimulsoft support directly https://www.stimulsoft.com/en/support

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to get the version which is fit for your (.NET) version, second try to use different versions of stimulsoft.

The error will be obvious if it contains stuff about your (.Net) version.

(For (.NET4) I used stimulsoft 2017.2.2.fix from soft98)